# Exclude site url from links RegEx

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I've a working RegEx I'm using to list down all the links found in a given html content

```html
<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)(http[^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>
```

This is actually working pretty good, the problem now is that I want to exclude from the results all the internal links (at a first look it would be enough to get only the ones including "http", but unfortunately is plenty of internal "absolute" links..)

Given that I know the website url, I don't need help to get that, so let's just assume is www.test.com / test.com

I had a look at the Negative Lookahead reference, but I'm not sure how it should be implemented in the existing RegEx..

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: [D̵̨̘̗̤̬̙̂̇̓͂͘͜o̴̜͌̊̍̄́̇̒̚ ̴̡̬͔̮͓̬̖̼͓͚̄͛n̸̦͔̐̒̂ǫ̶̢̡̝̝̭̝̤̰̍͒̂͌̄̊t̵̡̲̮̑͐̂̎͠ ̷̥̻̹̗̲̜̭̣̏́́̍͂͐͘͝p̸̘̩̳̯̫̣͚̲͓͚͊̈́͆̆͝͠á̷̼͓̟̣͋̃͗̈̊͠͝͝ŕ̷̢̘̝̲͂s̵̨̱͖͚̦͇̮̑͜ȩ̷̜̱̈͆͋͘ ̵̡̛̪̝̺̤̙̜͐̎̏́Ḣ̵̛̟̦͂̋̉̄̄͝͠ͅT̸̨͍̻̥̯̥͓̦͙͛̔̿̊̃̓͑̋͘M̸̼͎͑̈́̅͛̚L̷̲͝ ̷̨̇̅̐̄̃̋͐̃̕w̴͓̄į̸̢̙͚̩̰͋̒̃̏́̂́͘t̸̼̩̜̪̹̬͛̌͌́͜h̴͍̐̉̃̑̀ ̴̜͇̙̹̜̙̀̎̄́̂̑͗͋̅̚R̷̡͕̦͚͇̹̬̤͎̔̈́͛̍͜ē̸̩͓̘̺̐̇͠ġ̵̯̖͕̖̫̺̠̫͇͜ë̴̙͔̯̩̘͔̠̦͍́̔̈́̆̅̈́̿̆̕̚x̵̟̟̞̰̣͕͙̠͝](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5827005)

Comment: I'll give you a regex, give me a minute

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a *blacklist* of sites using an alternation
in combination with a `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.
This way the engine moves past the offending urls and cannot backtrack.

`(?:<a(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=\s*(?:(['"])(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?(?:www\.test\.com|test\.com)(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>.*?</a\s*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<a(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=\s*(?:(['"])([\S\s]*?)\2))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>(.*?)</a\s*>)`

https://regex101.com/r/hpwUr3/1

The stuff you want is:
 - Group 3 = url
 - Group 4 = content

Explained

```
 (?:
      # Begin Offender Anchor tag
      < a
      (?= \s )
      (?=                           # Asserttion for:  href  (a pseudo atomic group)
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           \s href \s* = \s* 
           (?:
                ( ['"] )                      # (1)
                (?:
                     (?! \1 )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*?
                (?:                           # Add more offenders here
                     www \. test \. com
                  |  test \. com 
                )
                (?:
                     (?! \1 )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*?
                \1 
           )
      )
                                    # Have the href offendeer, just match the rest of tag
      \s+ 
      (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

      >                             # End  tag

      .*? 
      </a \s* >
      (*SKIP) (*FAIL)               # Move past the offender
   |  

      # Begin Good Anchor tag
      < a
      (?= \s )
      (?=                           # Asserttion for:  href  (a pseudo atomic group)
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           \s href \s* = \s* 
           (?:
                ( ['"] )                      # (2)
                ( [\S\s]*? )                  # (3), Good link
                \2 
           )
      )
                                    # Have the href good one, just match the rest of tag
      \s+ 
      (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

      >                             # End  tag

      ( .*? )                       # (4), Content
      </a \s* >
 )
```